# R ggplot increase points by size and by color for same variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset and I have 3 variables. One of them I want to scale by size and color but unfortunately it does color the points but instead it places a black point on top of a colored point.

example:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=day_of_week, y=light, color = speed_limit,  size=speed_limit))  + geom_point()
```

and the out_put:

[image]

Any suggestions how can I merge the color and size to 1 so that they grow?

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it - create a `discrete` variable and plot both `color` & `size` using the variables with manual scales

Note that this end up not continous scales. In my personal experience, I found that create bucket for size & colors would help to have better control over the colors and better visualization especially in the data contains outliers.

```r
# Create some demo data
df <- data.frame(
  day_of_week = rep(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), 5),
  light = rep(c("Daylight", "Darkness - no lighting", "Darkness - light unlit", "Darkness - light lit",
    "Darkness - lighting unknown"), 7),
  speed_limit = runif(35, 20, 70)
)

# Using ggplot2 for obvious reason
library(ggplot2)

# create the discrete variables using cut
df$speed_limit_cut <- cut(df$speed_limit, breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
  include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE)
levels_count <- length(levels(df$speed_limit_cut))

# Create the colors scale coresponded to the levels in cut
color_scales_fn <- colorRampPalette(c("#142D47", "#54AEF4"))
manual_color <- color_scales_fn(levels_count)
names(manual_color) <- levels(df$speed_limit_cut)
# Create the sizes scale 
manual_size <- seq(1, by = 1, length.out = levels_count)
names(manual_size) <- levels(df$speed_limit_cut)

# Plot using the new variable
ggplot(df, aes(x=day_of_week, y=light, color = speed_limit_cut,  size=speed_limit_cut)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_manual(values = manual_size) +
  scale_color_manual(values = manual_color)
```

Here is the output

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>